# merging multiple png files to one long stripe png file on mac

Tags: image-processing, applescript, photoshop-script

I'm searching, searching but cannot find a way to do it. In a folder have about 1800 png files, same sizes. I need to create a long vertical stripe for every nine images, so same width but height 9 time bigger. So the result would be one file with image 1 to 9 (one on top and 9 at the bottom), a second with images 10 to 18, and so on. What should give about 200 files still in png (desinterlaced). The files name start at 0001.png and is sequential to about 1800.png (or more). Final files (vertical stripe) should be named like stripe0001.png and be sequential to about stripe0200.png (or more). I'm on mac. So it can either be an applescript or a script on Photoshop (in CS3).

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: My question is pretty simple: does someone know a script (applescript or photoshop) to do such a job ? I have to say I'm kind new to scripts, figuring mostly actions with the record button on photoshop. But here it's way out of my actual range

Comment: I think that is called "Filmstrip". Good Luck! Try this: https://www.google.com/search?q=creating+filmstrips

Answer (score 1):

I'd use ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick, with a shell script to separate the files into groups of nine, something like this:

```
for x in $*
do
convert $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 -append group_$1.png
shift;shift;shift; shift;shift;shift; shift;shift;shift
done
```

If using GraphicsMagick, use "gm convert" instead of "convert".
Use "+append" instead of "-append" if you want to make horizontal
strips instead of vertical ones.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with something like GraphicConverter, or any graphics program that is heavily scriptable.

You’ll need to break the script into steps as you write, and write it a step at a time. For example,

1. Act in groups of nine.
2. For each group, open each file in GraphicConverter (or whatever scriptable app you choose to use), closing at the end of each group.
3. For each group, generate the new filename and report on it.
4. For each group, copy files 2 through 8.
5. For each group, for file 2 through 8, after copying, append them to the first image.
6. For each group, after appending all 8 images to the first image, save it.

You will probably want to take, say, the first 27 images out into a separate folder for testing purposes, so that you don’t have to wait on all 1,800 images when testing. When you have it working on the first 27 images, add the next 81 images. If that works, try it on all 1,800.